# Problem in getting Minimum length using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Here i am retrieving minimum size of a text file inside a directory.But it gives `0` as a minimum size.But there is no 0 kb file inside that directory.

```
var queryList3Only= (from i in di.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     select i.Length / 1024).Min();
dest.WriteLine(queryList3Only.ToString()+" Kb");
```

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Is i the file name? And dividing an int by an int will produce an int. Try using 1024.0 instead

Comment: @lain: `i` is an instance of `FileInfo` i think.

Comment: @Danny Chen: I think you are right, i must be FileInfo and di must be DirectoryInfo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to select doubles not int's. if filesize is < 1024 then you will end with size 0

```
var queryList3Only= (from i in di.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     select (double)i.Length / 1024).Min();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have any files less that 1024 bytes then they will appear as zero as your integer division will be truncated.

```
1023 / 1024 = 0
```

You may find casting the values to doubles will get you an answer between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2):

`i.Length` is long. When `i.Length` is less than 1024, `i.Length / 1024` will return 0.

Use `i.Length / 1024.0` instead